# Positioning a slider in QT

Tags: qt, user-interface, slider

A colleague of mine created a video player widget all by code. So when I wanted to add one more slider at the bottom of the main slider I got into trouble. I tried setting its starting point but it doesn't seem to take that into account.

I tried a couple of basic functions like setPosition, setGeometry but they dont' work . I have included the image for better understanding of the problem 
I am also pasting a code snippet which get this together.

```
  QHBoxLayout *basicControlsLayout = new QHBoxLayout;
  basicControlsLayout->setMargin(0);
  basicControlsLayout->addWidget(open_button_);
  basicControlsLayout->addWidget(play_button_);
  basicControlsLayout->addWidget(position_slider_);
  basicControlsLayout->addWidget(stop_button_);

  int* a, *b, *c, *d;
  position_slider_->getContentsMargins (a,b,c ,d);
  QRect r(*a, *b, *c-*a, *d-*b);

  QHBoxLayout *basicScratchLayout = new QHBoxLayout;

  // basicScratchLayout->setGeometry(r);
  basicScratchLayout->addWidget (position_limit_slider_);
```

So How do I get those two to align up ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely `QGridLayout` is what you want in this case. I think that constructing grid like this would work fine, so your slider sizes and positions would always be in sync:
[image]

Code to make it work is approximately something like this:

```
 QGridLayout *layout = new QGridLayout ();
 layout->addWidget (open_button_, 0, 0);
 layout->addWidget (play_button_, 0, 1);
 layout->addWidget (position_slider_, 0, 2);
 layout->addWidget (stop_button_, 0, 3);
 layout->addWidget (position_limit_slider_, 1, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Predelnik :
So, this is what I got . Thanks . :) . I couldn't really do what you told me in the earlier post with the same problem where I wanted to super impose the three and get min, max and runner behavior yet though.

Comment: You're welcome. Maybe I'll look into is it possible to superimpose them without much pain or not if I have some spare time.